# Add thumbnail to custom post type Wordpress with Gutenberg

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, wordpress-gutenberg

I created a custom post type in Wordpress and I would like to add support for thumbnails. I have created the post type specifying support for thumbnails, but in the editing window of the post type page does not appear the option to specify a thumnail.

I'm using Gutenberg as an editor, with the classic editor, there's no problem. Any solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First add theme_support within functions.php

```
  add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'custom_post_type_name' )
```

Then add 'editor' and 'thumbnail' to supports and make sure you have show_in_rest set to true.

```
  'supports' => array( 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
  'show_in_rest' => true,
```

Otherwise it won't work in Gutenberg. Here is the documentation for supports:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_type_supports

Answer (score 0):

You nee to enable support for Post Thumbnails.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails

The common way is to add

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

in your functions.php

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug report regarding this issue.
Kindly refer to the link [Feature Image disappears only in Gutenberg with CPT.](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/46723)

Answer (score 0):

As most of common solutions around the web doesn't work I will put only that sometimes themes or plugins use

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'page', 'my_cpt_name' ) );
```

So it's worth to check this and add the cpt name to array.

Answer (score 0):

Add this on your functions.php:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```